# How can I put a split string into a list where the items are the chars?

Tags: python, list, split

For example, I want to split the string num, '123', by its characters (1, 2 and 3) and put it in a list, numlist. However, using `num.split()` it gives me `['123']`when I want `['1','2','3']`. Is this possible?

Comment: `list('123')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
num = "123"
numlist = list(num)

print(numlist)
```

Outputs:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a general way, when your `num` may be stored in a variable and you would need to add it to a list you can use the following:

```
num = 123
my_list = list(str(num))
my_list
```

Outputs:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is just to use `list()` like @Andrej Kesely suggested in the comments like the following:

```
s = '123'
res = list(s)
print(res) # ['1', '2', '3']
```

You can also use list comprehension if you will need to manipulate the way the splitting occurs:

```
s = '123'
res = [e for e in s]
print(res) # ['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

num = '123'

## string list

a = list(num); print(a)

## list of integers

x = [int(num) for num in a]; print(x)